# Java Encoding issue

Tags: java, encoding, ascii

When defining the below string on Java JDK 9 
String s = "एक गाव में एक किसान"
It throws the following error:
Unmappable character (0xE0) for encoding US-ASCII
I understand that it is UTF-8 encoded but as JDK 9 has default charset set as US-ASCII but I can't find how to change the default charset to UTF-8 from the code itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting the default Java character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

Comment: No, I want to change the default charset from within the code

Comment: `Unfortunately, the file.encoding property has to be specified as the JVM starts up` It is in the answer

Comment: is there anyway that i take user input in bytes and convert into string with utf-8 format?

Comment: There are 2 different issues: encoding of sources and encoding for IO operations in your code. When you have written some .java files in non-default encoding,you have to say java compiler what encoding it should use to read the sources to parse them correctly. The second issue is how you read/write data in your code. It also uses default encoding, but there is a lot of specific methods to read/write data using encoding explicitly like: InputStreamReader(InputStream in,String charsetName),
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out,String charsetName), 
String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)etc.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to change the default charset from within the code

Impossible<sup>1</sup>.

The source code is just text, it doesn't define the encoding used to store that text.

You can however decide that your source code is US-ASCII, so the encoding doesn't matter (excl. UTF-16, UTF-32, etc), by specifying all non-ASCII characters as Unicode escapes:

```
String s = "\u090f\u0915 \u0917\u093e\u0935 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u090f\u0915 \u0915\u093f\u0938\u093e\u0928"
```

Of course, it makes it difficult to know what the string says.

<sup>*1) Since Java doesn't support BOM's.*</sup>